# Snowflake load client encrypted file in snowflake from Azure

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load Client side encrypted file into azure and then load the file into Snowflake. The plan is to add the encryption Key in snowflake stage to decrypt the file.

However till now whatever I have tried has failed to successfully imply the process. Even after adding the Encryption Key, the data in snowflake is still encrypted.

I have followed the steps from below link
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html#ingesting-client-side-encrypted-data-into-snowflake

Below are the steps I did.
Encrypt the file using python. below code use cryptograpy, I have tried cryptodome as well but still the same result.

```
import cryptography
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64
# Get the key from the file
file = open('key.key', 'rb')
mykey = file.read()
file.close()

mykey = base64.b64decode(key)
print(mykey)

with open('Fileloacation/myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()


fernet = Fernet(mykey)
encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

# Write the encrypted file
with open('sf1.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted)
```

Once the file is encrypted. I load the file using Azure storage explorer and created the stage in snowflake as per below.

```
CREATE STAGE "mydb"."myschema".securedatge 
URL = 'azure://path' 
CREDENTIALS = (AZURE_SAS_TOKEN = '***********') 
ENCRYPTION = ( MASTER_KEY = '**********************');
```

As of now I tried to find any video demonstration or proper steps-by-steps process of cse in Azure, but could not find any.

Please suggest.

Comment: As per your steps the stage refers to an external location, so the file in that location will be encrypted, as this is expected. What do you mean by in Snowflake you still see the file encrypted? One you load data into a table then you should be able to see it (using SELECT statements), but the file itself on the stage will still be encrypted.

Comment: Yes the file in azure is encrypted and should be. however If I am doing select on the external stage. It should be decrypted, as the stage has master key. but it is not decrypting the record.

Comment: If the file displayed in the stage when using LIST? What error do you get when you try to SELECT?

Comment: list is showing the files. and select is also working (no error). only issue is it is not decrypting the file whereas I am expecting the file to be decrypted in select * from stagename.. since I have encryption key attached to stage as shown above